# c => c.ColumnName == null don't create c.ColumnName IS NULL at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am doing a query from EF as :

```
int? roleID = null;

db.Set<CompanyAccess>().Any(c => c.CompanyId == 1 || c.UserRoleId == roleID);
```

In this query, since `roleID` is null, the condition

```
c.UserRoleId == roleID
```

should be translated as `c.UserRoleId IS NULL` at runtime.

It was working well before I upgraded to Entity Framework 6. After the upgrade to EF 6, the `c.UserRoleId IS NULL` part goes missing at runtime, hence the desired filtering is not achieved.

Please if anyone has encountered such an issue can throw some light on how to fix it?

Thanks
PravinK

I tried `c.UserRoleId.Equals(roleID)` instead of `c.UserRoleId == roleID` but still when `roledId` is `NULL`, the runtime query is missing the `c.UserRoleId IS NULL` expression.

Comment: Could you show your `CompanyAccess` class, this might give insight into the matter. What I suspect is that the `UserRoleId` inside `CompanyAccess` is not of a nullable type.

Comment: It is like :public class CompanyAccess
    {
        public long? LicenseeId { get; set; }

        public long? UserRoleId { get; set; }

        public long CompanyId { get; set; }

        public long CompanyType { get; set; }
    }

Comment: @PravinKamane Maybe try `long? roleId = null` instead?  Or you could check for null and rather than `c.UserRoleId == roleID` do `c.UserRoleId == null`

Comment: Even doing c.UserRoleId == null dont give the translation to c.UserRoleId IS NULL at runtime

Comment: First of all you can't compare a long to an int. The Exception states that the runtime query is missing the `UserRoleId IS NULL` which suggests that the problem is within the database instead of in the code. Have a look if the column is nullable inside the database